# How to add class with listview to a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm very new to Android, so forgive me if this is a terrible question, but I've searched high and low and I've been reading lots of material and can't seem to figure this out. I've created an app in Eclipse using one of the default views (fixed tabs + swipe). I created a second class with a listview and I'm trying to add this class to load in one of the tabs.

**EDIT to include full MainActivity.java**

```
package com.sonnyparlin.gracietampa;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView;

            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                            container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                    dummyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.page1text)));
            } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {


                    // I want to add my listview here


            } else {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                        container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                        ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

My TechniqueActivity.java file:

```
public class TechniqueActivity extends ListActivity{

    public TechniqueActivity() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] technique_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.technique_list);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, technique_list));

    }

}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction so that I can populate the second tab of my application with the listview I've created in TechniqueActivity.java. Or maybe there's a completely different / better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually using any tabs. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) for the basic idea. If you're going to use tabs you need to (1) create the tabs and then (2) set your activity to be loaded by that tab. The code above just looks like you're creating one activity and then inflating that layout. The blog post provides a good overview of a simple 3 tab application which you can adapt to your case.

The other way to do this would be to use a `ViewPager` which you can [read more about here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). The `ViewPager` approach uses `Fragment` and not `Acitivity`. Basicly you create a `ViewPager` and an adapter which you then add instances of your fragments to. As you swipe the `ViewPager` rotates through the fragments in the order you add them to the adapter.

Those look like the 2 most relevant ways to approach this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after more research and playing around, I found the solution, which was basically what Rarw said in the second part of his answer, which was to use a Fragment instead of an Activity. So, I got rid of TechniqueActivity.java and created a TechniqueFragment instead. Then I call it in the getItem().

```
package com.sonnyparlin.gracietampa;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            Fragment fragment;
            if (position == 0 || position == 2) {
                fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
            } else {
                fragment = new TechniqueFragment();
                //setContentView(R.layout.technique_activity);
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView;

            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                            container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.page1text)));
            } else {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                        container, false);
                TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                        ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class TechniqueFragment extends Fragment {

        public TechniqueFragment() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView;

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.technique_activity,
                    container, false);

            ListView lv1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
            String[] technique_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.technique_list);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(lv1.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, technique_list));

            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```